# Selecting information from layer with the expression dialog in another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg

I want to get the value for an angle out of an attribute table of one layer into a function of another.

The function is for a line in the properties -> labels -> background for the rotation of a SVG.

I used `get_feature_by_id(layer, column)` to get the value but it got the error that the field was not found. Same with normal `get_feature`.
Why this does not work?

[image]